# Customer Controller and downloading a file (Apple Wallet - using PKPass library)

Tags: modules

I'm trying to create a controller for a user to download a membership card as a pass in Apple Wallet. I'm looking to use the [PKPass Library](https://github.com/includable/php-pkpass/tree/master).

I've got things set up and working using their example like this:

```
$pass = new PKPass(Yii::getAlias('path/to/cert.p12'), 'myPassword');
$data = [
  'description' => 'Membership Card',
  // etc as per example: https://github.com/includable/php-pkpass/blob/master/examples/example.php
];

$pass->setData($data);

$pass->create(true);
```

but get a 'Headers already sent' error when trying to download the pass. I feel like this is because the PKPass class is outputting to the browser before my module has finished processing the request.

So changing the last line to `$createdPass = $pass->create(false);` and then handling the output is probably what I want to do, but I'm stuck on how to get that `$zip` response back into my controller as a file to download. Here is the `create` method:

```
public function create($output = false)
{
    // Prepare payload
    $manifest = $this->createManifest();
    $signature = $this->createSignature($manifest);

    // Build ZIP file
    $zip = $this->createZip($manifest, $signature);

    // Return pass
    if (!$output) {
        return $zip;
    }

    // Output pass
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $this->getName() . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T'));
    header('Pragma: public');
    echo $zip;

    return '';
}
```

This might be more of a basic PHP question, but does anyone know how I could do that?

Comment: Not sure what you're missing here – if `$output` is `false`, you're already returning the `$zip`, so the controller can output it. What is not working? As a sidenote, setting headers and outputting content should not happen in a utility method, it should happen in the controller.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Whenever I see you respond to one of my questions I always get excited because I know it's going to be helpful! (I mean that sincerely) And indeed this is a good thing that I can't answer very well. I was just getting a "Safari can't download this file" error with the previous code. August's reply has helped push me in the right direction. Thanks again for the reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the Pass bundle is created in a [service](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/services.html), your controller should only be responsible for calling that method and preparing a response. As @MoritzLost said, setting headers from a service method (or allowing another library to control the HTTP response) is generally inadvisable—in part because those tools exist in Craft/Yii, and in part because you should be able to create a Pass and ZIP file without caring about when or where it will be used (say, precompiling a bundle in a background job or building one to be attached to an email).

To that end, your service might look like this:

```php
namespace mynamespace\myplugin\services;

use craft\base\Component;
use PKPass\PKPass;

class Passes extends Component
{
    public function createPass(): string
    {
        $pass = new PKPass('...', '...');
        $pass->setData([
            // ...
        ]);

        // Return the ZIP’s content, directly:
        return $pass->create(false);
    }
}
```

(This method could be parameterized so that it can look up an entry or whatever other info you need to create a unique pass!)

Your controller would look like this:

```php
namespace mynamespace\myplugin\controllers;

use craft\web\Controller;
use mynamespace\myplugin\Plugin;

class PassController extends Controller
{
    public function actionGetPass(int $id)
    {
        // Call service to create pass:
        $pass = Plugin::getInstance()->getPasses()->createPass($someArg);

        // Send the file’s contents:
        return $this->response->sendContentAsFile($pass, 'Pass File Name.pkpass', [
            'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.apple.pkpass',
        ]);
    }
}
```

We're using the built-in [`sendContentAsFile()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-response#sendContentAsFile()-detail) response method via the controller’s `response` property, and declaring the appropriate MIME type so that the client has a hint about what to do with the attachment.

Read more about sending files in the Yii documentation on [handling requests](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-responses#sending-files)!

Comment: Thanks August, this is great (and a good reminder of how much I still have to learn.) I think I'm close, but unsure on the `$this->sendContentAsFile` part. With that in place, I get a 'calling unknown method' error. Excuse my lack of knowledge, but how could I make that work?

Comment: Looks like I needed `$this->response->sendContentAsFile()` - got it working now! Thank you!!

Comment: Ah, shoot, you're totally right. Updating the answer accordingly!